# Concatenate index name in the Workbooks Object

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create For Each loop for a several workbooks; however I am not able to set the workbook name in the array and thus resulted into this. I'm stuck in trying to concatenate the workbook name.

Here's my code:

```
 'Open all .csv file in folder location

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If InStr(objFile, ".csv") Then
            Workbooks.Open (objFile)
        End If
    Next

    ' Declare variables
    Dim WrkBkPrm As Workbook
    Dim WrkBkSrc As Workbook
    Dim WrkShtPrm As Worksheet
    Dim WrkShtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim TextSrc(4) As String
    Dim SrcRng As Range
    Dim DRng As Range

   ' Assign values to TextSrc() Array
      TextSrc(0) = Cable
      TextSrc(1) = Care
      TextSrc(2) = MSD
      TextSrc(3) = Business

   'Set WrkBkPrm and WrkShtPrm values

   Set WrkBkPrm = Workbooks("MasterFile" & ".xlsm")
   Set WrkShtPrm = WrkBkPrm.Worksheets("Canvas")

   'Activate Canvas Sheet

   WrkBkPrm.Activate
   WrkShtPrm.Select
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Start For Each Loop
   For Each Src In TextSrc()

    Set WrkBkSrc = Workbooks(Src & ".csv")
    Set WrkShtSrc = WrkBkSrc.Worksheets(Src)

    'Copy loop for 1st section

    For i = 2 To 49
        For j = 7 To 25

        Set SrcRng = WrkShtSrc.Cells(i, j)
        Set DRng = WrkShtPrm.Cells(i, j)

        If SrcRng <> "" Then
        DRng.Value = SrcRng.Value
        End If

        Next j
    Next i

    Next Src

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Can you explain what error/outcome you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you work on the file as soon as you get hold of the relevant info you need.
Something like:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If InStr(objFile.Name, ".csv") <> 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Thisworkbook.Path & "\" & objFile.Name)
        '~~> Do your cool stuff with the opened CSV File
        wb.Close False '~~> Close without saving
        Set wb = Nothing '~~> Clean up although most of the time not necessary
    End If
Next
```

As for the route you took, for you to use *For Each Loop* on `TxtSrc`, you need to declare it as variant.
Something like:

```
Dim TxtSrc As Variant, Src As Variant

TxtSrc = Array("Cable", "Care", "MSD", "Business")
For Each Src In TxtSrc
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Thisworkbook.Path & "\" & Src & ".csv")
    '~~> More cool stuff here
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing
Next
```

It is **important** that provide the correct argument for the *Workbook Open Method*.
You should always include the complete path in string format. HTH.

Comment: The error I'm getting is in the TxTSrc Loop section. I guess you the problem lies in declaring both Src and TxtSrc as variant.

Comment: BTW! Thanks for your help! Just tried editing the code using your advise and it works now. Will just need to write the rest of the code for the macro.